# Перейти к концу строки кода в intellij-idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

Как быстро перейти в конец строки (если правил что в середине, что бы поставить **;** в конце)?

Использую для этих целей Ctrl+-> и Shift+Ctrl+-> нома мало ли есть способы быстрее.

Comment: Нашел в горячих клавишах что копирование строки (и вставку) можно делать без выделения, Ctrl+C/X/V, а так же дублирование Ctrl+D.
Остается вопрос с переходом к концу строки.

Answer (score 3):

Кнопка <kbd>End</kbd> создана как раз для этого (годах в 1970-х, наверное).

А рядом с ней кнопка <kbd>Home</kbd> - это чтобы в начало строки.

Answer (score -1):

Якщо на ноутбуці, то кнопка "End" знаходиться як альтернатива на клавіші "стілка вправо".

Тобто, треба натиснути відразу "Fn + End"

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык